# Change textView throught editText and button

Tags: java, android, button, textview, android-edittext

I'm trying to solve this code but I'm stuck with that.
I have 3 different text view (drink1Ml, drink2Ml, drink3Ml) which are initially set to ".
I have 3 text input (only numbers) I want to copy the text in the EditText and paste it in the thre text view throught a button ( add) that check if the first textview is empty than paste the text in it, if the second is empty and the first not then in the second... Ecc
The button doesn't work

```
add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            vol = volume.getText().toString();
            grad = gradazione.getText().toString();
            tempo = ultimoDrink.getText().toString();

            if (addDrink1Ml.getText().toString() == "") {
                addDrink1Ml.setText(vol);
                addDrink1Gr.setText(grad);
                addDrink1Hr.setText(tempo);
                volume.setText("");
                gradazione.setText("");
                ultimoDrink.setText("");
            } else if (addDrink1Ml.getText().toString() != ""
                    && addDrink2Ml.getText().toString() == "") {
                addDrink2Ml.setText(vol);
                addDrink2Gr.setText(grad);
                addDrink2Hr.setText(tempo);
                volume.setText("");
                gradazione.setText("");
                ultimoDrink.setText("");
            } else if (addDrink2Ml.getText().toString() != ""
                    && addDrink3Ml.getText().toString() == "") {
                addDrink3Ml.setText(vol);
                addDrink3Gr.setText(grad);
                addDrink3Hr.setText(tempo);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure about your initial problem, but use .equals() to compare Strings. i.e. if (addDrink1Ml.getText().toString().equals(""))

Comment: and if i want to use != for string? Like isn't equal

Comment: (!addDrink1Ml.getText().toString().equals(""))

Comment: Thansk a lot, this helped me! :D